# What is the best way to convert selenium scripts into karate feature files?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, karate, ui-automation

i have a selenium script i want to create a feature file in karate framework using the scenarios and assertions in the selenium script. can anyone tell me the best approach to do this. Either it is to make an engine to first convert the scripts into a json file and then use a script builder to create a feature file or is there any method. Please enlighten me with your suggestions.

Comment: unfortunately I don't know of any short cuts for this. just curious, why are you doing this ?

Comment: shifting from selenium to karate